# Datalist line break when records with same ID detected

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, data-binding, datalist

Kinda hard to explain, but i'll try. I have a datalist that is populated by a call to a stored procedure. The thing is, when rows with the same ID is detected i want it to break and add it under the first record and so on....

Illustration -- > Stack [23,45,566,676,787,878,23,23] (these represent record ID's)

---

23 
 23 
 23

---

45

---

and so on.

Currently it's adding a row to a different data item as show below.

---

23

---

23

---

23

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be during the row databinding, check the current value, value previous, and next value. If you have a match between the current and previous, you have a group, then check the next row to come (from your original data source) and if it is different, then insert your empty line.

Comment: Seems rather complex and a waste of time. Anyways I built a simpler solution thanks anyways. God speed